# Customize Bash Prompt and apply the modification for all logged users

Tags: bash, python, bashrc

I have a linux with dynamic IP address. I would like to change the bash prompt according to the current IP. A python script is responsible for this connection and his launched at boot.

```
os.system('export PS1="\u@'+str(self.ip)+'>"')
```

The command is executed but this doesn't modify anything outside the environment block of the python process : not all the users logged or those who will log in the future.

The idea was then to change .bashrc for each user or /etc/bashrc. It will solve the problem for new connections but not for the opened.

Comment: Does this script run periodically? Does it report the system's _own_ address straight from ifconfig, or does it report the results from querying a remote "whatismyip" service?

Comment: it's more complicated than that. I want to add other python variables. I tried to simply a little bit ;)

Comment: The same story applies to all of them. There is no good way to "push" any variables to other processes -- they must themselves "pull" the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this doesn't modify anything outside the environment block of the python process

It doesn't even do that. It modifies the environment block of the child `/bin/sh -c "export..."` process that system() invokes, and the modifications are immediately lost – they do not propagate 'upwards' to the Python process either. (Check `os.environ["PS1"]` if in doubt. In fact, why aren't you setting os.environ directly?)

(Besides that, Bash has a separate set of "shell variables". There's significant overlap between the two – environment variables are imported during shell startup, and shell variables can be marked for export to child environments – but the key point is that *even if* you update Bash's environment block "from the outside", it won't actually update the *shell variable* $PS1 that Bash really uses.)

That said, a common trick to update a process' environment "from the outside" (and practically the only way) is to attach a debugger to the process and call the corresponding function that modifies the environment as seen by the program itself:

```
$ gdb -p <pid>
(gdb) p (int) putenv("FOO=bar")
$0 = 0
(gdb) p (char*) getenv("FOO")
$1 = 0x55bb09f61404 "bar"
```

This will actually work with PS1 because Bash carries its own implementation of getenv() and putenv(), overriding the usual libc version. That custom implementation doesn't actually update `environ`, instead it updates the corresponding shell variable. Calling `putenv("PS1=foo")` through a debugger will therefore update the shell prompt.

But it's quite frankly a horrible solution to the real problem. If you want the shell prompt to always show the current IP address, just make *the prompt itself* check what the correct value is.

Bash allows you to include literal expansions such as `$var` or even `$(cmd)` within $PS1, and they will be expanded every time the prompt is shown. For example (note the `\$` being escaped):

```
$ PS1="<now=\$(date +%X)> " ↵
<now=03:27:02 PM> ↵
<now=03:27:04 PM> ↵
<now=03:27:07 PM> ↵
<now=03:27:08 PM> ↵
```

So in order to apply this to your "IP updater" script,

1. Instead of trying to change all environments, simply make the script write out the IP address to a file (say, `/tmp/current-ip`).
2. Make your shell prompt read from that file, using the `$(< filename)` expansion:

   ```
   PS1="@\$(</tmp/current-ip)>"
   ```

That's it. You don't need to go through all environment blocks to do this – each shell will automatically re-read the file the next time the prompt has to be displayed. For example:

```
$ echo 1.1.1.1 > /tmp/current-ip ↵
$ PS1="@\$(< /tmp/current-ip)> " ↵
@1.1.1.1> ↵
@1.1.1.1> echo 22.22.22.22 > /tmp/current-ip ↵
@22.22.22.22>
```

Comment: How am I ever going to catch you up if you keep writing such excellent answers? ;)